# Is it true that every hypergraph with a large "semi-shattered" set has large VC dimension?

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph

Given a hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ and a set $X\subseteq V$ of vertices, let $int(X)$ be the number of distinct intersections of edges with $X$, i.e.
$$int(X)=|\{S\subseteq X, \exists e\in E, e\cap X=S\}|.$$

$X$ is called *shattered* if $int(X)=2^{|X|}$, i.e. if $int(X)$ reaches its maximum feasible value.

> **Question:** Is the following claim true?
>
> **Claim:** If $H$ has a set $X$ with $int(X)\geq 2^{|X|}/2$, then $H$ has a shattered set of size at least $|X|/2$.

*Remarks:*
$\bullet$ The two constants "2" are somewhat arbitrary here, I really want to find out if this claim is true for some pair of (not necessarily equal) constants.

$\bullet$ The claim is true if $|X|\leq 4$ but my proof cannot be extended to higher values.

$\bullet$ My motivation comes from questions related to the [*Vapnis-Chervonenkis dimension*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) of a hypergraph, i.e. the biggest size of a shattered set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the Sauer–Shelah lemma (mentioned in the Wikipedia article on VC-dimension linked in your question).

> **Theorem** Let $\mathcal F$ be a family of subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  If $|\mathcal F| > \binom n 0 + \binom n 1 + \cdots \binom n k$, then $\mathcal F$ shatters a set of size $k+1$.

Note that the inequality is tight, as with equality $\mathcal F$ might not contain any sets of size $k+1$.  So the Sauer–Shelah lemma will answer your question whatever constants you use in place of $1/2$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! I see why it works with a constant 2 (because $2^{k}/2>\sum_{i=1}^{k/2}\binom{i}{k}$, but I don't see how to derive such a bound for $2^k/c$: I always get an additional $\log k$-factor...

Comment: @FlorentFoucaud, That might not have been the clearest way for me to phrase it.  I meant that given $n$, and a family with $\alpha 2^n$ members, then you can work out the best you can hope for using Sauer–Shelah.  If $\alpha$ is not $1/2$ then the answer won't be something nice like $\beta 2^n$ (with $\beta$ independent of $n$) because of how the binomial distribution bunches up in the middle.